# I am being asked to resign with only a week left on my postdoc contract, should I?

Tags: job, quitting, contract

My two year postdoc contract is ending next week.  I am looking for a job at a bank in my state now.  My university's personnel office has contacted me asking me to resign; that is to say, they're asking me to bring the employment relationship to an end (a few days) before the automatic end date in the contract.  What should I do?

Comment: Why do they want you to resign? Hopefully not because you are looking for a job. Hopefully not because you have done some unmentionable thing.

Comment: Since you answered yourself, is this a hypothetical or are you asking on behalf of another?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Comment: There isn't a problem with a self answer (and I do it myself elsewhere), but I'm just curious about the question.

Comment: Regardless of the self-answer which clarifies the ambiguity, you should edit the question to sort out whether you mean quit or keep going for another year.

Comment: @BillBarth The question specified the contract ends next week.  There's nothing involving "another year" here.

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist, could have been a contract with an option to quit or re-sign for more years. Usually not on this short a notice, but maybe you clearly delayed on deciding, and if you wanted to stay, you could just keep on truckin' doing the same work for a new, extended time.

Comment: @BillBarth I've never seen a postdoc contract with any kind of built-in option like that.  Anyway, I think the word "ending" in the question is clear.  If you're familiar with a contract I'm not familiar with, please add an answer.

Comment: I do not understand the question nor the answer. If you have a fixed-term contract that ends within a week, what legitimate reason could there be to resign instead of just letting the contract end?

Comment: OK, do what you like. Sometimes postdocs get hired on at the end of their postdocs as Research Associates or similar titles to continue their work. We've certainly hired on a postdoc to continue and would consider that "re-sign"ing even if it was an entirely separate contractual agreement instead of a "re-signing" clause in the existing contract. I agree with @Roland that there's no need to quit a fixed-term contract that's ending. Your job is just over. Find another. At least in TX in the US. Local and national laws and your contract may say different.

Comment: @Roland The question is about an illegitimate request to resign.  It's a trick to deny severance.

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist Then why are you flipping the reasoning in your answer? There is no advantage for you in resigning. So, you don't do it. Everything else doesn't matter.

Comment: @Roland sounds like you agree with my answer.

Comment: No, I don't. There is no need to check anything (except you obviously should know your work contract). You just tell administration: "No, thank you."

Comment: Why would one be entitled to severance pay at the end of a fixed-term contract?

Comment: @Roland If you post that as an answer I'll vote for it.

Comment: @Ian No, I do not expect duplicates.  Roland and Louic's comments are quite helpful for this situation.

Comment: @PieterNaaijkens In Great Britain, because of section 136(1)(b) of the Employment Rights Act 1996 as amended by the Fixed-term Employees (Prevention of Less Favourable Treatment) Regulations 2002.

Comment: What does your PI say? I find it all very weird, and for better or worse suspect there is additional information that is not disclosed.

Comment: @DanielHatton: thanks, I was not aware of that!

Comment: @JonCuster Yes, there's a very poorly written employment contract that is not disclosed here.

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist Is the contract so badly drafted that it's not actually clear whether it's a fixed-term contract or an open-ended contract?

Comment: @DanielHatton No.  Good edit.

Comment: OK.  And is the contract so badly drafted that it entitles you to much more severance pay than the employer either intended or is required by public law to offer?

Comment: @DanielHatton I do not know the intentions of the contract author as there's a large bureaucracy associated with the university.  I am not aware of any requirement by law.

Comment: Also, if the present contract is an extension/follow-on top a previous contract, check that the extension letter doesn't mean you are entitled to severance benefits (inherited from the original) that are better than those that you would get if you joined now...

Answer (score 9):

There is no need to resign if you have a fixed-term contract. When your contract ends, your employment ends. That's it.

Unless administration gives you a good reason, you don't need to consider this request any further[1]. Since there is no possible advantage for you, you simply decline to do this.

[1] I'm assuming a normal western employment system. The answer might be different in places like, e.g., India, where employees have fewer rights.

Comment: 'there is no possible advantage for you' In Great Britain, there is one (very unlikely but not impossible) edge case: if you're in an hourly-paid role with variable hours and the employer has recently reduced your working hours (perhaps to zero), then resigning formally through the proper channels can (in combination with a couple of other formal procedures) _create_ an entitlement to severance pay (Employment Rights Act 1996 section 150(1)).

Comment: @DanielHatton OK, if that is the background, HR intends to do OP a favor and would have explained this.

Comment: Oh, I don't for one moment think the situation OP is encountering is an example of that edge case.  I just thought the phrase 'no possible' was a bit strong.

Comment: @DanielHatton I think such edge cases are covered by "unless administration gives you a good reason".

Comment: Not quite.  Administration may, in theory, _have_ that good reason, but not _give_ that good reason to the person of whom they're making the request.

Answer (score 5):

- Read your employment contract and handbook very carefully.  Particularly look for information about severance payments.  Also check for information about notices that must be provided, and when they must be provided.
- If you are entitled to a severance payment, resigning will likely give up that payment.   Do not do that.
- Do not agree to any document falsely claiming you have been provided with a notice.  If you agree you received a notice, you may give up pay in lieu of notice.
- Find out about your local government's unemployment insurance/benefits.  They may not apply if you resign.

Comment: Also, I think that in some countires you could lose the right to certain benefits if you resign instead of get fired.

Comment: @Louic this applies to unemployment benefits in Germany, for example.

Comment: I would hope that in places where some sort of severance is due even at the end of a contract except when you resign, that trying to induce someone to resign would be illegal. Not so?

Comment: Note that in some jurisdictions, the entitlement to a severance payment at the end of a fixed term contract may follow automatically from public law, and therefore may not be explicitly mentioned in a contract.